# Get records corresponding to maximum serial number

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I want to get records corresponding to maximum serial number

```
slno            date      name

1-22-12-2011-1  1/1/2012  Amrutha
1-22-12-2011-2  1/1/2012  Amrutha
1-22-12-2011-3  1/1/2012  Amrutha
```

I want a query which returns data corresponding to slno `1-22-12-2011-3`. I mean maximum in last postion. How can I write a query for it? My DBMS is MySQL.

Comment: what you have tried so far and where you have stucked? please show us your query...

Comment: **maximum in last postion** OR **maximum in slno**?? What if I have data as `1-22-12-2012-1`

Comment: Hi all thanks for the response . As the slno field is varchar the order by didnt makes any difference in my result.I will explain with help of a example.in my question name and date fields are similar.but i want last added data of amrutha. ie 1-22-12-2011-3 .I cant change my database.my query is select * from u_investment where investorcode='0809/   115'  order by SUBSTR(slno,14,LENGTH(Receiptno)) asc . but it didnt works.I want only one row actually which contain maximum slno of amrutha

Answer (score 2):

***Assuming that you have data in same format like `1-22-12-2011-1`***

below should work

```
SELECT MAX(CONCAT(
           substr(slno,1,1), 
           substr(slno,3,2), 
           substr(slno,6,2),
           substr(slno,9,4),
           substr(slno,14,1)))
as "newslno"
FROM myTable;
```

This will give you the maximum `slno` from your table

### [Demo at sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ad0e/18)

---

### Update 1

I think you need to add AND condition in WHERE statement... `AND name='Amrutha'`

```
SELECT MAX(CONCAT( 
                 substr(slno,1,1), 
                 substr(slno,3,2), 
                 substr(slno,6,2), 
                 substr(slno,9,4), 
                 substr(slno,14,1))) as "newslno" 
FROM u_investment 
WHERE investorcode='0809/ 115' AND name='Amrutha'
```

Comment: hi   when i check this query select * from u_investment where investorcode='0809/   115'    i can see max slno as 1-22-12-2011-29 when i run SELECT MAX(CONCAT(
           substr(slno,1,1), 
           substr(slno,3,2), 
           substr(slno,6,2),
           substr(slno,9,4),
           substr(slno,14,1)))
as "newslno"
FROM u_investment where investorcode='0809/   115' ;   this query it returns 1221220118 .i changed substr(slno,14,1))) to substr(slno,14,2))) but no change

Comment: @Amritha : Please update question with data that you get for `select * from u_investment where investorcode='0809/ 115'`. I need to see what you get...